# MongoDB: Save 2 different document's reference into one field of other document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have three collections: user, questions and answers. The user can select either questions and answers as favourites. I need to show the questions and answers that the user has marked as favourite.

Which is the best approach to do it?

My first thought was to create a array field in both questions and answers which saves the users_id who liked that question or answer. Then, to get the information I should make two queries: db.questions.find({favourites:user_id}) and db.answers.find({favourites:user_is}). However, I would like to have the information just in one query.

I also thought to save in the user collection an array with questions_ids and answers_ids. But I am not sure that is the best approach and as well, I don't know how to define this using Mongoose.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the latter approach. So on your user model, you'd have the following defined:

```
{
  favoriteAnswers: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Answer'
    default: []
  }],
  favoriteQuestions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Question'
    default: []
  }]
}
```

With that defined in the model, your "mark as favorite" logic could be something like:

```
const user = await User.findById(someId).exec()
const answer = await Answer.findById(someAnswerId).exec()
const question = await Question.findBYId(someQuestionId).exec()

user.favoriteAnswers.addToSet(answer._id)
user.favoriteQuestions.addToSet(question._id)
await user.save()
```

Then when you need the documents just call `.populate()`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
const user = await User.findById(someId).populate('favoriteAnswers favoriteQuestions').exec()
```